# Function passing by reference accepts reference to class with operator()

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

So, the more I think about this the weirder its legality seems. When I pass my an instance of my memoizer functor into its constructor, the compiler doesn't complain. How should 'f' be read in the memoizer template? It seems that with the same type declaration `OutputT (&f) InputT` it can refer to a function by reference, or--and I thought this was illegal--a reference to a member function, namely `operator()` of an instance of the class `memoizer<int,int>`. Should f instead be read as 'a reference to something with an `operator()` defined?'

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

template<typename OutputT, typename InputT>
class memoizer
{
private:
    OutputT (&f) (InputT);
    std::map<InputT,OutputT> dat;

public:
    memoizer( OutputT (&f) ( InputT ) ) : f(f) { }

    OutputT operator()( InputT t )
    {
        if( dat.count(t)==0 )
            dat[t] = f(t);
        return dat[t];
    }
};

int fib( int n )
{
    if( n < 2 ) return 1;
    return fib( n-2 ) + fib( n-1 );
}

int main()
{
    memoizer<int,int> fib_memo( fib );
    memoizer<int,int> fib_memo_memo( fib_memo );    

    std::cout << fib( 12 ) << "\n";
    std::cout << fib_memo( 12 ) << "\n";
    std::cout << fib_memo_memo( 12 ) << "\n";
}
```

I mean, don't get me wrong: I'm glad it works, it just seems kind of 'magical.' Thanks in advance.

Comment: it works because of type erasure. type erasure is a little 'magical.'

Comment: If you repeat a typename more than once or if it's annoying to read (both in your case), use a typedef. `typedef OutputT function_type(InputT);`.

Comment: @GManNickG Yeah, totally. There's a bunch of silliness in this example. In retrospect, I was pretty much proving to myself that a memoizer template is a bad idea (at least for recursive functions). A non-tail recursive function at that. But regarding the typedef... would you make that public or private? Thanks. Maybe that's a different question.

Comment: @NathanAndrewMullenax: Since it's used in the public interface, I would make it public. (As private as is meaningful is my general guideline.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're tricking yourself. `fib_memo_memo` is not a memoizer whose `f` member variable contains `fib_memo`. Your initializer there is actually using the implicit copy constructor, so `fib_memo_memo` is just a copy of `fib_memo`. You can verify this yourself by adding

```
memoizer(const memoizer &m) = delete;
```

You'll start getting errors like

```
error: call to deleted constructor of 'memoizer<int, int>'
    memoizer<int,int> fib_memo_memo( fib_memo );
```